# Who designed monokai color scheme?

Tags: sublimetext2, color-scheme

I am in love with Monokai color scheme. Did the makers of Sublime Text designed it or is it in use before sublime text arrived?

The second part of the question is that can I freely copy it for my own editor. Does anybody holds copyright over it?

Comment: This is a complex legal topic beyond the scope of this forum. Why not try the "legal" sister site?

Comment: I got the information I was looking for here itself - otherwise I would have posted it on the sister site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's not programing related.

Comment: I have re-asked it on graphic design site. You can close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monokai is online blog of designer Wimer Hazenberg who originally created theme for TextMate editor in 2006. See here: http://www.monokai.nl/blog/2006/07/15/textmate-color-theme/

As far as I can see, all other variations and ports of this theme are distributed under various open-source licences so I guess it's free to use but to be sure you can always mail original author, mail is on his blog.

Comment: Its seems that question will be closed here so I have re-asked this at graphic design site - http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64979/who-designed-monokai-color-scheme. Kindly repost your answer there.